# Communicating confidence in an R forecast's correctness with non-mathematicians

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validation

I work for a software company that is building its first data science application, a program which forecasts sales based on previous sales.  We have certain groups within the organization who are asking for assurances that the forecasts are "correct": in the past they have run into data models that were poorly explained which shook their confidence.  Our current plan is to capture the data for a forecast and try and recreate the forecast using the tool this application is replacing, probably some kind of spreadsheet.  Are there better strategies than this?  Do any of them not involve learning a bunch of maths as the first step?

Comment: You could hire experienced people who already understand the mathematical principles :-).

Comment: It sounds like someone oversold them in the past.  I would under promise and over deliver focusing on a long term strategy to win their trust.  I would start by saying that my forecast is not "correct" and then explain the concept that all models are wrong, but some are useful. Then I would try and explain in very simple terms why the new model is more useful than the old one. If you can bring this utility back to dollars all the better.

Comment: You could explain in detail the out-of-sample performance (which presumably you have ready to hand). Appropriate displays and descriptives should be able to be conveyed in a fairly non-technical way.

Answer (score 3):

An easy and intuitive approach is cross-validation. Tell the managers you built the model on a longer time frame, say, the sales data from time 2010 to 2015. Then show them the real sales of 2016 (e.g. a time series) and overlay the prediction made by the model. Give some sort of measure of forecast error (such as MSE). It will become immediately clear how well the models worked *into the future* (i.e. 2016).

Of course this is only an example but you could construct others along these lines. Besides being a handy demonstration to managers there is some real information in this on whether it makes sense to apply these models.